# Requesting location in watchOS and its effects on battery

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to create a low-power watchOS app that will only periodically (every 5 minutes or so) need an updated but precise location. The key word there is need. The app certainly could provide better information if it were getting location updates consistently but the goal is for this app to be low power. That being said (and I am not sure if this is possible) if another app is constantly streaming location in the background it would be nice to get those updates too if that does not have extra battery cost.

Is there a way to only request location periodically? Is this actually better for the energy impact of the app?